# Node js application on Openshift error

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

[This is the link to my github repo](https://github.com/kksandyrox/node_test)

I am trying to make an application in node js, a simple cron that sends email every second. 
I want to host it on Openshift server. But I dont know/can't understand how to make it work.
Did a lot of research but still just cant make it work.

I would like you'll to review my code, specially package.json and server.js
The error that i get is when I echo the log

```
You specified a Timezone but have not included the `time` module. Timezone funct
ionality is disabled. Please install the `time` module to use Timezones in your
application.
events.js:72
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EACCES
at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1003:19)
at listen (net.js:1044:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1110:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/53671fef4382ec57c1000097/app-root/
runtime/repo/server.js:3:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

I am just a beginner to node.js, any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :** This scripts works perfectly fine on LOCALHOST. Even without having to install the "time" module.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that the module 'time' is missing.

try:

```
npm install -g time
```

EDIT

I was trying to run your code in my local, and I get this same error. 
When i type npm install -g time, I get error:

> Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

So, maybe You should install python.exe first, on your production machine?
In windows You have to  set the environment variable, e.g:

```
set PYTHON=D:\Python\bin\Python.exe
```

I have no more ideas

Comment: Hi @cieszynka `You specified a Timezone but have not included the time module. Timezone funct
ionality is disabled. Please install the time module to use Timezones in your
application.`
This warning/error is not the concern.

The problem is that the script doesn't work on live i.e Openshift. It works fine on Local.

The issue i am concerned about is the `Error: listen EACCES`
and `DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8`

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json, add "time" module to the dependencies object:

```
"dependencies": {
    // other modules...
    //  :
    //  :

    "time": "*"
},
```

Comment: I added the time module, but still no success.
When i open this link [http://node2test-kksandyrox.rhcloud.com/](http://node2test-kksandyrox.rhcloud.com/) , i get "Service Temporarily Unavailable" error message. 
I think if the error from the Log "DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8", can be resolved, it might fix it. But I'm not completely sure.

Comment: That "Service Temporaily Unavailable" error means server is not running.  Usually, this means after pushing your code on OpenShift, the server started, then died, or died after you hit the URL.  It looks like some serious error there.  I might have to look at your server code and/or log (from OpenShift) to figure out what's wrong with it.  If you can copy and paste the error and stacktrace from the log here, that would be helpful.

Comment: All of m server code is present in [server.js](https://github.com/kksandyrox/node_test/blob/master/server.js), and entire code repo at [Entire code repo](https://github.com/kksandyrox/node_test)

Is there any other log you want me to paste? other than what I originally pasted in my post above?

Comment: Sorry sandeep, I totally missed the link to the source code in your original post. I'll take a look at it to see what I can find.

Comment: I cloned the the code repo and put it on OpenShift, it started ok.  I even got the index.html content (including tags) back when I hit the URL.  Try:  "git add node_modules/time", commit, then push to see if that works.